# How to force Nuget to ask for authentication when connecting to a private feed?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am getting 401 unauthorized error when trying to restore packages from my company's feed at xxx.pkgs.visualstudio.com (xxx is company name). I want to clear or reset the authentication information Nuget is using and get the authentication prompt again in Visual Studio 2015 to enter the username and password.

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reset user data to force Nuget to ask for authentication when connect to a private feed.

```
devenv /resetuserdata
```

You also can store the username and password to the Nuget config file for corresponding feed.

```
nuget.exe sources add -name {your feed name} -source {your feed URL} -username {anything} -password {your PAT}
```

Comment: `dev /resetuserdata` does not purge the old credential, it does not even delete the source which is stored in `%appdata%\NuGet\NuGet.Config`.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to Edit/Clear the Nugget credentials from Credential Manager of your machine.

Comment: I checked but saw no credentials related to the NuGet package I'm trying to access.  So it's some other issue.  Anyway, problem has been happening for years, not sure why Microsoft just can't add a button to reauthenticate against the NuGet repo you're trying to access.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem this month and wasted a few hours of googling to find a solution.

In my case, the private feed is a package repository hosted on NEXUS, and I use AD password to connect to the repository. It worked well for the 1st time, but when I changed my AD password later, `Install-Package` cmdlet just failed with 401: Unauthorized without prompting for the new password.

I cannot download `nuget.exe` either due to strict corporation security regulation.

The solution I found is manually updating the credential in [Credential Manager](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026814/windows-accessing-credential-manager).